# How to avoid the multi-line text view shift up and obstacle the above edit text view while typing in the edit text view?

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile-application

I'm recently learning Android app development. And after I added a multi-line scrollable text view to display the output (based on the input from the user from the EditText), this text view will shift up and obstacle the edit text view which is above it while I'm trying to type something in the edit text view.

Is there any way to stop the shift up of this multi-line text view?

Before typing:
[image]

While typing in the edit text view...
[image]

Following is my xml code for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="My New App"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:onClick="doPress"
        android:text="Press me"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Student ID: "
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputText"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outputContent"
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="236dp"
        android:background="#99C369"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:background="#F3BABA"
        android:onClick="doClear"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:textColor="#DD6363"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can You edit Your question and add activity XML code?

Comment: Hi, I just added my XML code for this layout. Please check it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="My New App"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Press me"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="#F3BABA"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:textColor="#DD6363"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:text="Student ID: "
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputText"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputText"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/outputContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#99C369"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="@string/long_string"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The thing that was making Your layout like this was `android:scrollbars="vertical"`. So I up it in the frame and now it is not interrupting Your Views.

Result (before and after clicking EditText):

[image]

And don't forget to add:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputContent)).setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

in Your activity class to enable scrolling in output TextView.

---

You don't even need FrameLayout and You can just add this TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/outputContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="64dp"
    android:background="#99C369"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="@string/long_string"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputText"
    />
```

The only thing that You have to set is height. It has to be `0dp` and constrained to bottom and top. Then You can apply margins that You want

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually figured out that every time when the last view item's bottom linked to the parent view's bottom, it will shift up while typing. But still, thanks so much, I will test your suggested solution on my side.